# Where do I put the Blender folder on linux?

Tags: installation, linux

It might be a silly question: where do I have to put the folder extracted from .tar.bz2 in a linux machine (Debian)? Usually I use a repository to install it but with the experimental versions I never know where to put it and I don't even know how to link the executable to the gnome application menu. Any help, please?

Comment: It is traditional to use /opt/ for additional software, personally I keep blender versions  in ~/src/

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I prefer to put it in a directory called *software* inside my home directory. What you may want to do is edit your `.profile` and add it to your `PATH` so you can call Blender easily from the terminal.

Comment: If you want to be able to add it as a desktop entry, you will have to copy the `blender.desktop` file either to `~/.local/share/applications` for the current user or `/usr/share/applications` to have it for all users.

Comment: @rjg I'll try it later. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Penny If this helped you solve your problem, I'll add it as a proper answer (instead of just a comment).

Comment: @rjg I was at work and I couldn't try from there. I just tried and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Penny what particular part didn't work?

Comment: @rjg I've placed the 'blender.desktop' file in the '/usr/share/applications' as you said but it does't show up in the gnome application menu, I've logged out and back in and even restarted the machine.

Comment: @Penny you also need to modify your `PATH` *or* edit the `blender.desktop` so that it contain the full path to Blender's binary.

Comment: @rjg I've edited the line `Exec=PathToTheExecutable` in the `blender.desktop` file and it worked. Thanks. Now how can add your answer as a proper answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply unpack it into Documents folder, and it works fine

Comment: Ok so you can put it anywhere you want as far as you have permission to access to that folder. And what about a a link to the gnome application menu? Is that possible or better to start it by CLI?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure about gnome, but guess it is possible. Is it that important, that you need to start blender by CLI?@Penny

Comment: It is not so important I can easily start it up by CLI, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as an answer, if it was useful to you, thanks @Penny